# Android Internal File

Tags: java, android, file

I have created a file using FileOutputStream in my app,

```
fos = this.openFileOutput("foo.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Now, I want to check if the file exists, using

```
 File file = new File("foo.txt");
     if (file.exists()) {
         file.delete();
         Log.d("tag", "im here");
     }
```

If the file exists I want to delete it. But my code does not seem to reach "im here". Is my approach wrong? How can I correct it? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the directory in which to look for the file. This can be achieved through the [`getFilesDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()) method.

```
 File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "foo.txt");
 if (file.exists()) {
     file.delete();
     Log.d("tag", "im here");
 }
```